# Need to suppress fillStackTrace() for all exceptions on a given thread

Tags: java, performance, exception

We have a high volume Java application (100s of millions of tx) that can encounter runtime exceptions at any point - the logic is created by users and it's impossible to anticipate every type of error condition.  A simple example is a Null Pointer Exception NPE that may only occur for 1M of the 100M records.

The problem is that whenever Java throws an exception it incurs an expensive fillStackTrace().  Depending on stack depth (time cost seems proportional - and we have deep stacks) the performance penalty can be 40+ times slower than no exception calls.

I know how to create custom exceptions and suppress fillStackTrace(), so that helps when I can detect a problem and throw my own exception, but I can't figure out how to get in front of something like an NPE and avoid the fillStackTrace().   I have tried bytecode manipulation (security violation to try to adjust Throwable), overloaded the Thread and created a [0] stack in getStackTrace() (the internal stack trace is done in native code, so this isn't called).   I'm out of options and need help.

Note - forcing the user to write better expressions isn't a viable option, we have hundreds of users (and plan to have 1000s) writing these expressions, note they're in Groovy, but the exception cost issue is independent as they happen lower in the Java portion of the stack.

Here's a simple test illustrating the problem:

```
public class TestExceptionPerformance {

    @Test
    public void testMissingFieldException() {
        exceptionTest(1f, 10_000_000, 100);
        exceptionTest(null, 10_000_000, 100);
    }

    private void exceptionTest(Float value, int iterations, int stackDepth) {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int exceptionCount = 0;

        for (int i=0; i < iterations; i ++) {
            try {
                multiplyMe(value, i, stackDepth);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                exceptionCount++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("With " + iterations + " transactions and " + exceptionCount +
                " exceptions thrown at stack depth " + stackDepth + ": " +
                (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");
    }

    // perform multiplication deep in stack
    static private float multiplyMe(Float value, int multiplier, int recurse) {
        if (recurse > 0) return multiplyMe(value, multiplier, --recurse);
        return value.floatValue() * multiplier;
    }

}
```

Results:

With 10,000,000 transactions and 0 exceptions thrown at stack depth 100: 1,431ms

With 10,000,000 transactions and 10,000,000 exceptions thrown at stack depth 100: 43,912ms

Comment: If you check if a value is not null, before call a method on it it will never throw an NPE. That is the better way than supressing Standard functions.

Comment: If you let people run arbitrary code, why does it matter which part of that arbitrary code is expensive? It doesn't seem to make sense to make exceptions cheaper by removing stacktrace, while this might break otherwise valid code. If someone relies on being able to inspect stacktraces of exceptions, would this be considered unsupported by your service?

Comment: This isn't a technical issue, it's a social or economic issue, and you are addressing the wrong end of the stick. As @Hulk says, why does it matter?

Comment: Would love some answers that focus on the question vs. questioning the validity of the need.  Low code, self-serve solutions are a huge trend.  Tools that manage that process well (mine does) can be a tremendous accelerator.  This is restricted to parts of my code that is very well managed, custom thread management, error handling, etc.  Questioning the question isn't helpful, although I see it so often, this isn't Facebook.  Java's implementation of stack tracking is very slow, so I need an alternative.

Comment: And to ease any moral objections, any exceptions in this very managed part of the code is immediately caught and translated into something meaningful for the user - e.g. "Error calculating 'price' on missing value 'item'" - this stack-less exception will not flow up the chain and cause havoc.  It's just that in order to even get the exception at millions a second is prohibitive and I'm looking for creative ideas on how to solve what is a valid engineering problem.

Comment: I only know about `-XX:+OmitStackTraceInFastThrow`, but AFAIK the omission is on by default. I'm afraid, you need to build your own JVM or train your users a bit (e.g., by giving low priority to code throwing a lot).

Comment: Thank you - yes, I have the ability to cache and re-throw a single pre-filled exception for all expressions that exceed a threshold of exceptions, but it's not ideal, at some point it triggers an 'all fail' situation when it would be better to know which 50% fail.   Low-priority is tough as it's a real-time system, if a calculation is delayed then the whole answer is delayed.  Even an exception is an answer....

Comment: Note - I found -XX:-StackTraceInThrowable which does indeed omit the stack trace.  However it's no faster, exceptions are still 40x slower, so it seems Java still calculates the stackTrace but doesn't save it?  Also a blunt instrument, impacts all exceptions, not just the threads I'd like to target.